# Java Mail API error; duplicate entry: javax/mail/MultipartDataSource.class

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, gmail-api

While generating signed APK,I am getting this error. I am sending an e-mail through the Gmail with Java mail API in project. 
When run it on phone there is no error, but when try to generate an apk the below error occurs. Thanks.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/mail/MultipartDataSource.class
```

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lkNZ.png)

Here are my gradle dependencies;

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('./libs/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android-assembly:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.mail.jar')


}
```

And this is my Mail.class

```
public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!user.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && !to.equals("")
            && !from.equals("") && !subject.equals("")
            && !body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO,to);

        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(body.toString());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        msg.setHeader("X-Priority", "1");
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how many libs folders you have? `./libs` and `libs`

Comment: 5 libs, there are unused libs.  @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: You should clear from local lib section.

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thank you so much :) @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, there were some unused libs in lib folder. As @IntelliJAmiya 's recommend, removed them and problem solved.